# Deserializing JSON text in VB12

Tags: json, vb.net, json-deserialization

i've searched everywhere and cannot find a solution to deserialize the following:

```
[
   {
     "picture":"URL_TO_PICTURE",
     "link":"URL_TO_SITE"
   },
   {
     "picture":"URL_TO_PICTURE",
     "link":"URL_TO_SITE"
   },
   {
     "picture":"URL_TO_PICTURE",
     "link":"URL_TO_SITE"
   }
]
```

my class file looks like this:

```
Public Class BonusItems
    Public Property picture As String
    Public Property link As String
End Class
```

i'm trying to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` with no luck at all...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: tried this.

```
Dim json As String = "[ {""picture"":""URL_PIC_1"", ""link"":""URL_LINK_1""}, {""picture"":""URL_PIC_1"", ""link"":""URL_LINK_1""} ]"
Dim Items As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)))(json)
```

but I'm not sure if its right nor do I know how to use the text. I'm so lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deserialize direcly to a list of your class:

```
Dim json As String = "[ {""picture"":""URL_PIC_1"", ""link"":""URL_LINK_1""}, {""picture"":""URL_PIC_1"", ""link"":""URL_LINK_1""} ]"

Dim items As List(Of BonusItems) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of BonusItems))(json)
```

The deserialize should take care of the rest, so long as things match up properly.

Comment: thank you. I just figured it out a couple minutes ago and didn't realize that you replied.

Comment: `Dim Items As List(Of Items) = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Items))(json)`